# Flutter - parse data from json is never completed

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to retrieve from an API a list of data.
This is the response from the API:

```
{"permission_requests":[{"id":1,"created_at":"2020-11-02","reason":"Aliquid cum autem id reprehenderit quam quis voluptate enim dolorem magnam doloremque et.","status":"cancelled","date":"06 Nov - 10 Nov","note":"Odit a exercitationem iure culpa voluptatem.","is_pending":false,"type_id":7},{"id":5,"created_at":"2020-11-02","reason":"Rerum incidunt explicabo accusantium nemo commodi quos sed et.","status":"refused","date":"13 Oct - 17 Oct","note":"Corporis ad omnis animi.","is_pending":false,"type_id":2},{"id":11,"created_at":"2020-11-02","reason":"Eveniet sed laudantium vitae perspiciatis molestiae sint minus dolores dolor numquam maxime facere deleniti velit.","status":"cancelled","date":"26 Sep","note":"Debitis perferendis officia aliquam dolor recusandae.","is_pending":false,"type_id":7},{"id":14,"created_at":"2020-11-02","reason":"Ut natus corporis necessitatibus et maiores accusamus repudiandae quas commodi consequatur ratione optio velit ducimus aut.","status":"accepted","date":"26 Sep","note":"Unde possimus laudantium doloribus voluptate ullam.","is_pending":false,"type_id":2},{"id":17,"created_at":"2020-11-02","reason":"Ut vel ea minus sint nemo et ex aut repellendus recusandae ex laboriosam sed aliquam veniam voluptas.","status":"pending","date":"26 Sep","note":"Minima ullam itaque quae ex inventore voluptatum.","is_pending":true,"type_id":4},{"id":24,"created_at":"2020-11-02","reason":"Rerum dignissimos est deserunt dolor aliquam qui repellat sequi quasi culpa rerum.","status":"accepted","date":"19 Sep - 2h","note":"Architecto ab inventore id est.","is_pending":false,"type_id":5},{"id":29,"created_at":"2020-11-02","reason":"Quas aspernatur impedit ea porro accusamus quas voluptatem magni temporibus velit error suscipit ab molestias in omnis.","status":"refused","date":"19 Sep - 2h","note":"Sunt beatae sit quia voluptates et enim cumque ut.","is_pending":false,"type_id":5}]}
```

And this is my code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:richiesta_permessi/const.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'package:richiesta_permessi/exceptions/exceptions.dart';
import 'package:richiesta_permessi/models/permission_request.dart';
import 'package:richiesta_permessi/repositories/authentication.dart';

abstract class PermissionRequestsRepository {
  Future<List<PermissionRequestModel>> getPermissionRequests();
  Future<bool> sendCancelRequest(String permissionRequestId);
}

class RestPermissionRequestsRepository extends PermissionRequestsRepository {
  List<PermissionRequestModel> permissionRequests;
  var httpClient = new Dio();

  @override
  Future<List<PermissionRequestModel>> getPermissionRequests() async {
    try {
      Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
      String token = prefs.getString('user_token') ?? null;

      if (null == token) {
        throw PermissionRequestsException(
          message: 'Non è stato possibile recuperare la lista delle richieste',
        );
      }

      httpClient.options.headers['content-Type'] = 'application/json';
      httpClient.options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
      Response response = await httpClient.get(kGetPermissionRequestsUrl);

      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        throw PermissionRequestsException(
          message: 'Non è stato possibile recuperare la lista delle richieste',
        );
      }

      final permissionList = response.data['permission_requests'];

      final List<PermissionRequestModel> permissionRequests = permissionList.map((value) => PermissionRequestModel.fromJson(value)).toList();

print('The list is done');
          
      return permissionRequests;
    } catch (e) {
      throw PermissionRequestsException(
        message: 'Non è stato possibile recuperare la lista delle richieste',
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> sendCancelRequest(String permissionRequestId) async {
    try {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      throw PermissionRequestsException(
        message: 'Non è stato possibile annullare la richiesta',
      );
    }
  }
}
```

This is the PermissionRequestModel:

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class PermissionRequestModel {
  final String id;
  final String reason;
  final String status;
  final String note;
  final String date;
  final bool isPending;

  PermissionRequestModel({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.reason,
    @required this.status,
    @required this.note,
    @required this.date,
    @required this.isPending,
  });

  factory PermissionRequestModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return PermissionRequestModel(
      id: json['id'].toString(),
      reason: json['reason'],
      status: json['status'],
      note: json['note'],
      date: json['date'],
      isPending: json['is_pending'],
    );
  }
}
```

The app has a BloC that call the repository and the request is correctly made, it call the API and retrieve the data.
The data is stored in the variable but seems that the `fromJson` is never completed, I have tried to print the `value` and it pass only once, can't figured out why.

Can't understand where the problem is, the `print('The list is done');`is neve reached.

EDIT:
I have changed the code, now I have added a simple for loop:

```
List<PermissionRequestModel> permissionRequests;
for (int i = 0; i < permissionList.length; i++) {
        permissionRequests.add(PermissionRequestModel.fromJson(permissionList[i]));
}
```

even with this code it do not return anything, if I manually add the data with this, it works:

```
permissionRequests = [
        PermissionRequestModel(
          id: '1',
          reason: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
          status: 'cancelled',
          note: 'Nulla facilisi. Donec mi risus, fringilla a felis ut, auctor placerat leo. Vivamus non placerat eros. Donec quis ullamcorper velit. Vestibulum nec ante efficitur, elementum urna et, feugiat est. Maecenas vel cursus nulla.',
          date: '20 ottobre',
        ),
        PermissionRequestModel(
          id: '2',
          reason: 'In in eros non sapien tempor egestas at nec tellus',
          status: 'refused',
          note: 'Nulla facilisi. Donec mi risus, fringilla a felis ut, auctor placerat leo. Vivamus non placerat eros. Donec quis ullamcorper velit. Vestibulum nec ante efficitur, elementum urna et, feugiat est. Maecenas vel cursus nulla.',
          date: 'Dal 20 al 22 ottobre',
        ),
        PermissionRequestModel(
          id: '3',
          reason: 'Nam ut condimentum dui. Nulla sed ultrices lacus. egestas at nec tellus',
          status: 'pending',
          note: 'Nulla facilisi. Donec mi risus, fringilla a felis ut, auctor placerat leo. Vivamus non placerat eros. Donec quis ullamcorper velit. Vestibulum nec ante efficitur, elementum urna et, feugiat est. Maecenas vel cursus nulla.',
          date: '20 ottobre - 3 ore',
        ),
      ];
```

How is this possibile? Whats the difference?

EDIT 2:
ok the problem is the `permissionRequests` when I try to use `.add`, for some reason it just try to parse the first element and then it runs forever

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if anyone should ever get the same error the problem is on the initialization of the list.
Don't know why but this do not work:

```
List<PermissionRequestModel> permissionRequests;
permissionRequests.add(Object)
```

while this works:

```
List<PermissionRequestModel> permissionRequests = []; 
permissionRequests.add(Object)
```